# Change Transaction Isolation level for DATABASE MySql in google app engine

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine, isolation-level

I'm trying to change my transaction isolation level in my database MySql with Gooogle App Engine.

I want to set it to 'READ-COMMITTED' and I want to set binlog_format to 'ROW'

This should make it :

```
SET GLOBAL tx_isolation = 'READ-COMMITTED';
SET GLOBAL binlog_format = 'ROW';
```

But database's users in Gooogle App Engine don't have the special permission required for the above instructions.

Is there an other way to make these changes ?